# Display only time and no date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

[image: I want to only display the time from this, is it possible to cut from model or view]

Using Asp.NET MVC4, how am I able to only display the time without the Date component?

Comment: Look into TimeSpan and dateFormatting

Comment: Fixed grammar to better explain the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Structure at MSDN. You can use `DateTime.ToShortTimeString()` method.

Example:

```
//Initialize the DateTime object to March 9, 2015 3:02:15 AM.\n");
DateTime myDateTime = new System.DateTime(2015, 3, 09, 3, 2, 15);
myDateTime.ToShortTimeString(); //result: "3:02 AM"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("3/1/2009 07:00:00 AM");

dt.ToString("HH:mm");    // 12:00    // 24 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 12:00 AM // 12 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("H:mm");     // 12:00    // 24 hour clock
dt.ToString("h:mm tt");  // 12:00 AM // 12 hour clock
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this :

```
TransactionDate.ToString("HH:mm")
```